# Not in clause in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hql

How do I achieve something like -->

```
Select sm.memCd, sm.entityName from MemberSBandAP sm 
where sm.memStatus='Active' and  sm.entityType='M'  
and  sm.memCd not in (select l.userName from Login l) 
order by sm.entityName DESC, sm.memCd"
```

basically how do I write a not in clause in hibernate?

I was referring to [this tutorial section 14.10 Expressions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)

in there they say that a not in can be directly used in the query string, but the query is not returning any records. Goggled for other examples but most of the places it says that we need to criteria class. Is it really required? Can't we directly write a sub query and use not in? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Sweta

Comment: What is it doing when you execute that query?

Comment: what type does sm.memCd have?

Answer (score 2):

`not in` is a valid HQL expression.

Make sure that the values returned by the subquery match to the values of the filtered field.

Answer (score 0):

use like this =>  sm.memCd not in **elements** (select l.userName from Login l)